# apt-get fails behind corporate firewall - Does the network require authentication

Tags: networking, server, apt, updates, proxy

I am trying update and install additional packages to my new Ubuntu Server 14.04 - This is installed on a VM environment inside a corporate firewall. However I cannot get apt-get to work. Here is what I have done so far.

Base install 14.04 LTS
Tried to run `sudo apt-get update` and get

```
E: GPG error: http://au.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
```

I have tried `sudo apt-get install <tools>` as well but this also does not work. I have read lots about this on this forum and others. I have configured proxy in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and also called this file `30Proxy` as advised by another post. I also added the proxy settings in /etc/environment but still fails. I checked the values are shown in env. I have tried with and without the `User:Pass@Proxy:port` setting but still not working.

I can ping the server without any issue.

I tried disabling the IPv6 interface but not change.

I tried installing desktop as well and get the same issue - However I can browse with firefox - no authentication required and without adding proxy anywhere.

As far as I know, apt-get uses http and ftp but I also saw someone mention **port 53** - this I think is blocked by the corp firewall.

I am installing a plone server and can use wget to get the plone package without any errors. So general networking is OK.

When I try `sudo apt-get install python-setuptools` it reads package lists etc and prompt to install. I confirm and it tries the Get1 to the archive. Reports Fetched 81.7 kB then fails with the following

```
E: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-setuptools/python-setuptools_3.3-1ubuntu2_all.deb Size mismatch
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing.
```

Obviously tried `apt-get update` and `--fix-missing`.

Interesting - when I check the file path it reports as failed, it appears wrong. If I browse with my desktop I get file not found. It appears to be missing a pub in the path as in
http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-setuptools/python-setuptools_3.3-1ubuntu2_all.deb

So then I tried to edit the source.list in `/etc/apt` but that didn't work either.

So I tested something else. On my desktop which is a Windows 7 I installed the same Ubuntu server package in Virtual Box. Then if I connect to ADSL (so no corp firewall) I can run the apt-get without any issue and it all works as it should. No special config. So I guess the paths in source.list are OK and it seems to point to authentication of some sort.

Being a windows environment, my username is a domain authentication although we do not use proxies any more, there are still some on the network. The proxy I am configuring I have verified. There is no obvious authentication happening for me to access the network, but it may be hidden in the windows domain login. I did try that also
`://domain\\user:pass@proxy:port`
(I removed the http at the beginning of the above as I am not allowed to post more than 2 links being a novice).

But that does not work.

So I am at a loss - Is it a port blocking issue? Can I change the port? Can I use another method to install the packages without too much pain?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks Pete